# Woocommerce Back End Order - Customer Not Found

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I have problems with placing an order for customers using the back end of woocommerce, on the customer search drop down, some users cannot be found by the system, thus not populating the necessary fields required to complete the order. What seems to be the problem here? Thanks in advance for any help. Thank you.

The users are migrated from another database using sql commands.

On the image below, it shows that the customer is not found, I have users with that given name.

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console? Also, is this only for certain customers? Or does this happen for all customers? If your customers are all imported, try adding a new one and seeing if they show up when searching.